# how can I print string from a list by the integer that I assign to them

Tags: c#

I new C# learner and I my question is
I have list with 3 item that gives rank from user input .
I can find min value that give from input but how is possible to show what value is for what item ?

thankyou!

my code is in the below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace Console1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] ranks = new string[3] { "take", "take2", "take3" };
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < ranks.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enter rank " + ranks[i] + " :");
                int f = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                list.Add(f);

            }
            
            int besti = best(list);
            int badi = bad(list);
            double calculator = ave(list);
            Console.WriteLine("the average is :"+ calculator+" bad movie is : " +badi+" best movie is : " +besti);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
        public static double ave(List<int> user_rank)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < user_rank.Count; i++)
            {
                sum += user_rank[i];
            }
            double q = (double) sum / user_rank.Count;
            return q;

           
        }
        public static int best(List<int> bestmovie)
        {
            int a = bestmovie.Max();



            return a;

        }
        public static int bad(List<int> badmovie)
        {
            int b = badmovie.Min();



            return b;

        }

    }
}
```

I want to see which items get minimum rank according user input?

Comment: You create a model class with a string property and an int rank property. Then you set the ranks in the respective instance.

Comment: ^^ that way you can order or select by rank and get the the instance from which you then can query the name (or whatever the string represents).

Comment: Unrelated: I'd also recommend to use `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`.